# (R) Generate a semi-orthogonal random matrix

Tags: r, orthogonal

I need to generate a random NxK matrix (where N > K), where the columns K are orthogonal random vectors.

An option I tried is to generate a squared orthogonal matrix with size NxN and then select the first K columns, but I wonder if there is a more efficient way of doing so.

Current code (in R):

```
library(pracma)
Z <- rortho(N)[,1:K]
```

Comment: Please read the info about [how to ask a good question](http://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-ask) and how to give a [reproducible example](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269). This will make it much easier for others to help you. Also, add your existing code.

Answer (score 0):

You can do that with the `rstiefel` package:

```
library(rstiefel)
rustiefel(N, K)
```